# Some Folder isn't created when publishing mvc 3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5

When I published the asp.net mvc 3 application from visual studio 2010 to IIS 7, Some of the folder is not published to the localhost. I have folder under the Content folder in the asp.net mvc 3 application named profileimage folder which is not created to the localhost directory under wwwroot folder. But other folder like css, img, js inside content folder is created. I have used filesystem to publish the application to localhost. I have searched looking for problem and found that the Build Action of properties should be content but profileimage folder properties doesn't show BuildAction properties. What might be problem that some folder is not created in the localhost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the folder is empty it won't be published. One possibility is to put an empty file within this folder and set the Build Action to Content for this file.

A ticket [has been opened](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/546356/publish-deploy-does-not-deploy-empty-folders) on MSConnect and the workaround is to add a dummy file to the folder.

Comment: the folder is contains image file already and image file properties doesn't have Build Action option... Or, file means what type of file should be

Comment: Every file must have Build Action property.